# Given that names of parameters are lost during compilation, how does Spring autowire by parameter name?

Tags: java, spring, reflection

Consider following configuration with two beans of the same type created:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = TwoStrings.class)
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public String one() {
        return "one";
    }

    @Bean
    public String two() {
        return "two";
    }

}
```

Another bean that depends on the two beans above is created by component scan:

```
@Component
public class TwoStrings {

    public final String a;
    public final String b;

    @Autowired
    public TwoStrings(String one, String two) {
        this.a = one;
        this.b = two;
    }

}
```

The names of local variables/parameters are lost during compilation and are not available at runtime:

[image]

However, Spring somehow autowires two `String` beans correctly. The example test below

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class )
public class Example {

    @Autowired
    private TwoStrings twoStrings;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(twoStrings.a);
        System.out.println(twoStrings.b);
    }

}
```

prints

```
one
two
```

Given the name of constructor parameters are lost, I would expect Spring to throw the exception saying that there is more than 1 bean of type `String`, however Spring somehow autowires beans using parameters names.

The question is how Spring knows the names of constructor parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring is [using debug information](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-core/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java#LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass%28java.lang.Class%29) in this case - it will fail if you compile your code without debug information, i.e. with `-g:none` flag of [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

Extract from [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-ctor-arguments-resolution):

> Keep in mind that to make this work out of the box your code must be
>   compiled with the debug flag enabled so that Spring can look up the
>   parameter name from the constructor. If you can’t compile your code
>   with debug flag (or don’t want to) you can use @ConstructorProperties
>   JDK annotation to explicitly name your constructor arguments.

Java 8 has introduced a way for reading this information using [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getName--) but the classes has to be compiled with a `-parameters` flag of `javac`

Comment: What is a debug flag? That's not a VM option, right? How can I control it in IntelliJ?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak it is enabled by default - in IntelliJ it is configurable in Settings \ Build, Execution, Deployment \ Compiler \ Java Compiler \ Generate debugging info

Comment: How does Spring accesses these debugging information? It cannot be reflection API, right?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Why cannot it be reflection API?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I have updated my answer with this information

Comment: @Kayaman I am compiling the code with debug information. Spring can see parameters names, but I still cannot get it via reflection API - see the screenshot in my question.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak you need to add `-parameters` flag to java compiler